# In vi/vim, adding a integer for a specific digital column

Tags: vim, vi

I have a file, for example, as follow:

```
HEAD 100 ABC 12 24 12.5
HEAD 101 ABC 10 20 11.9
HEAD 102 ABC 13 18 15.4
HEAD 103 ABC 14 21 17.6
HEAD 104 ABC 16 23 13.4
```

how could I add a number (like 5) to column 2 of every row? It will be

```
HEAD 105 ABC 12 24 12.5
HEAD 106 ABC 10 20 11.9
HEAD 107 ABC 13 18 15.4
HEAD 108 ABC 14 21 17.6
HEAD 109 ABC 16 23 13.4
```

I try to do it in vi command mode, I try

```
:%s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/g
```

But it add every digit in the row.

THANKS!!!

Comment: `%norm 5^A` would work and is pretty short. *`^A would be <c-v> followed by <c-a>*

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, in block-visual mode (`Ctrl-V`) select the numbers to be incremented:

```
HEAD 100 ABC 12 24 12.5                                           
HEAD 101 ABC 10 20 11.9                                           
HEAD 102 ABC 13 18 15.4                                           
HEAD 103 ABC 14 21 17.6                                           
HEAD 104 ABC 16 23 13.4
```

Then press keys: `5 Ctrl-A`

---

The visual approach is quick, but to give another example suppose you want the output:

```
HEAD 150 ABC 12 24 12.5                                           
HEAD 151 ABC 10 20 11.9                                           
HEAD 152 ABC 13 18 15.4                                           
HEAD 153 ABC 14 21 17.6                                           
HEAD 154 ABC 16 23 13.4
```

that is add 5 to the numbers to the 7th column. You could either use the visual method with `50 Ctrl-A`. Or use specific-column matching (`\%c`):

```
%s/\%>6c\%<8c\d/\=+5/
```

Comment: THANKS! This is actually an even easier way (for small row numbers?)

Comment: If your input file contains many rows then after typing `Ctrl-V` you can move down n-many rows with `nj`.

Comment: emmm, looks like the ctrl-v does not work in visual block mode in my vim version (7.4). Seems ctrl-v in visual block is newly added.

Comment: If `:echo has('visualextra')`  returns 1 then the current version  of Vim supports block visual mode.

Comment: no, I am in linux. the Ctrl-a works in regular mode, but just not work in the visual mode.

Answer (score 3):

You were very close, but just don't use a global match, instead use:

```
:%s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+5/
```

This will only replace the first match (in this case the desired second column).

Output:

```
HEAD 105 ABC 12 24 12.5
HEAD 106 ABC 10 20 11.9
HEAD 107 ABC 13 18 15.4
HEAD 108 ABC 14 21 17.6
HEAD 109 ABC 16 23 13.4
```

Comment: MANY THANKS! Also, how do I match a specific digit column? This will make it more convenient, for example, if I want to edit the column 4 of my file above, but not the first digit column.

Comment: Then use block-visual mode.

Comment: yes, good idea! that works!! Think it is enough for some simple edit.